# Prove (1 + x)^n + (1 - x)^n < 2^n by using Binomial Theorem

Tags: recurrence-relations

Hi my boss asked me to resolve this equation:

Prove `(1 + x)^n + (1 - x)^n < 2^n` by using Binomial Theorem `-1 < x < 1` and `n >= 2`.

Comment: @Artes - It can be Mathematica related, e.g. [Proofs of Inequalities](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/Tricks9-3/Tricks9-3_2.html).

Comment: Conditions were amended by Kardashev3 ruling out `x = 1`.

Comment: When $(a+b)^n> a^n+b^n$? set $a+b=1+x>0$ and $a-b=1-x>0$

Answer (score 3):

This question seem to be about mathematics, not about *Mathematica*. However, *Mathematica* can help us to deal with this problem.

It can proof the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^n+(1+x)^n$:

```
Sum[2 Binomial[n, k] x^k, {k, 0, n, 2}]
```

> ```
> (1 - x)^n + (1 + x)^n
> ```

We know that $x^k \le 1$ for $-1\le x \le 1$. Therefore $(1-x)^n+(1+x)^n$ is less than or equal to

```
Sum[2 Binomial[n, k], {k, 0, n, 2}]
```

> 2^n

Thereby $(1-x)^n+(1+x)^n \le 2^n$ for $-1\le x \le 1$.

*Mathematica* can help us to avoid simple mistakes in mathematical calculations.

Comment: ... for k >= 0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Expressing the left-hand side in [binomial form](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Binomial_Theorem) :-

```
lhs[x_, n_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*x^k, {k, 0, n}] + 
     Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*(-x)^k, {k, 0, n}]
```

It is evident that the result does not exceed 2^n.

```
Show[Plot[{lhs[x, 2], lhs[x, 3], lhs[x, 4]}, {x, -1, 1}], 
   Plot[{2^2, 2^3, 2^4}, {x, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]